# Получить свойство объекта из этого же объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, объекты

Есть приложение VueJS. Нужно получить из объекта одно из свойств этого же объекта.

```
data: {
        users: [],
        api: {
            endpoint: 'http://afshuka/api',
            getUsers: this.endpoint + '/getUsers'
        }
    }
```

Но по запросу к `this.api.getUsers` выдает следующее: `undefined/getUsers`

Как мне получить `endpoint` внутри этого же объекта.

Comment: Никак. На момент чтения getUsers объекта ещё не существует. Можно объявить endpoint заранее и использовать в нужных местах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил банально. Вне объекта Vue создаем это:

```
const API_ENDPOINT = 'http://afshuka/api';
const API = {
    getUsers: API_ENDPOINT + '/getUsers'
};
```

И спокойно обращаемся :)

Answer (score -1):

this в данном случае содержит контекст объекта вью. Сделай computed метод

```
 getUsers() {
   return this.api.endpoint + '/getUsers'
 }
```

и добавь в

```
data: {
        users: [],
        api: {
            endpoint: 'http://afshuka/api',
            getUsers: this.getUsers
        }
    }
```